# PHP share objects across multiple sessions

Tags: php, oop, singleton

How can I have user A and user B has the same instance of an object?  I guess this would be across two different sessions.

Comment: What kind of object? Is it data, or a database connection?

Comment: There will be several, database object, employee object.  I want to use a singleton pattern.  I would have a locking mechanism inside the employee to prevent employee from being editing by two ppl at the same time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way would be to serialize the object and then putting it in a file or a database to share it between requests. However if two request happen exactly at the same time, they will each have a different object to work with and the last request to finish will be the only one that will be saved. So you will need some kind of locking mechanism to prevent that.

http://ca.php.net/manual/en/function.serialize.php

Comment: Lock by storing the serialization in a table having the locking userID in a field of the serialization record. Then lock with "Update ser set uid = ME where ME is NULL;", Check for getting the lock by selecting back, release the lock by nulling out the uid when updating the serialization.

Comment: If two users are logged on at the same time, is the object they share synced? or is it like having the object in two differant states.

Comment: It would be like having the object in two different state. Since every request happen in it's own process there is no easy way to share an in-memory object between to instance of a script.

Answer (score 3):

Checkout APC,

http://www.php.net/manual/en/intro.apc.php

You can store the object to cache like this,

```
apc_store('my_key', $obj);
```

and retrieve from another page/session, like this,

```
$obj = apc_fetch('my_key');
```